# Как мне получить данные, где DRF хранит информацию о админах?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Вопрос в следующем.. После того как пользователь зарегистрировался и авторизовался ему присваивается Токен. Насколько я понимаю, токен у простых пользователей и админа разные. Если человек зашел как администратор, то мне нужно знать об этом, а именно чтобы приходил не только токен но и status: admin. Все это должно быть по url http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/login/, когда человек авторизовывается.
Примерно такая структура должна быть :

```
{
 "status:admin,
    "user": {
        "email": "eva1@eva.ru",
        "token": "b'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6NywiZXhwIjozM30.NJ3CbEpn0eYPA4HiX5o7Fv-VRs-cAfSpYnCVFrHJ0gE'"
    }
}
```

Я вот и не пойму, где хранится информация о пользователях со статусом **админа** и как его вывести.

**models.py**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        """ Создает и возвращает пользователя с имэйлом, паролем и именем. """
        if username is None:
            raise TypeError('Users must have a username.')

        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users must have an email address.')

        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password) #Устанавливает пароль пользователя на заданную необработанную строку, заботясь о хешировании пароля
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        """ Создает и возввращет пользователя с привилегиями суперадмина. """
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Superusers must have a password.')

        user = self.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True #Обозначает, что у этого пользователя есть все разрешения, без их явного назначения.
        user.is_staff = True #Определяет, может ли этот пользователь получить доступ к сайту администратора.
        user.save()

        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Временная метка создания объекта.
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # Временная метка показывающая время последнего обновления объекта.
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def token(self):
        return self._generate_jwt_token()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def _generate_jwt_token(self):
        dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)

        token = jwt.encode({
            'id': self.pk,
            'exp': int(dt.strftime('%S'))
        }, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')

        return token
```

**renders.py**

```
class UserJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    charset = 'utf-8'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        errors = data.get('errors', None)
        token = data.get('token', None)
        if errors is not None:
            return super(UserJSONRenderer, self).render(data)

        if token is not None and isinstance(token, bytes):
            data['token'] = token.decode('utf-8')

        return json.dumps({
            'user': data
        })
```

**serializers.py**

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализация регистрации пользователя и создания нового. """

    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        min_length=8,
        write_only=True
)

    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'token']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    # username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True) 
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True)
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        email = data.get('email', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)

        if email is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'An email address is required to log in.'
            )

        if password is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'A password is required to log in.'
            )

        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

        if user is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'A user with this email and password was not found.'
            )


        if not user.is_active:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'This user has been deactivated.'
            )


        return {
            'email': user.email,
            #'username': user.username,
            'token': user.token}

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Ощуществляет сериализацию и десериализацию объектов User. """
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        min_length=8,
        write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password', 'token',)
        read_only_fields = ('token',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)

        for key, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, value) 
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
class RegistrationAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer
    renderer_classes = (UserJSONRenderer,)

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        print(user)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


class LoginAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    renderer_classes = (UserJSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        print(user)

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
class UserRetrieveUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    renderer_classes = (UserJSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_data = request.data.get('user', {})

        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            request.user, data=serializer_data, partial=True
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user', UserRetrieveUpdateAPIView.as_view()),
    path('user/registration/', RegistrationAPIView.as_view()),
    path('user/login/', LoginAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У пользователя есть еще поле `is_staff` и свойство `is_superuser`

Добавьте в сериализатор

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password', 'token', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')
        read_only_fields = ('token', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')
```

Если будет ошибка, добавьте в сериализатор поле `is_superuser = serializers.BooleanField()`

[Источник](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py)